# Will symbol links in a Qt resource file consume extra space?

Tags: qt, resources, qt4, qt4.8, rcc

I have an image file named `image-generic.png` and a symbol link to it, named `image-generic-x.png`, both of them are included in a Qt resource file.

Now If I compile the program, image-generic.png would consume some space, but would image-generic-x.png do that too? Does Qt resource file honor symbol link?

I wasn't able to find anything about it in the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

Compile your program with and without the symbolic link file and compare the size of the executables. This will tell you whether the resource was included twice or if the resource compiler is smart enough to figure out that the resources actually refer to the same file.